# Handlebars lookup in array

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I have JSON object:

```
{
    groups: [
        {id: 1, title: "group1"},
        {id: 2, title: "group2"},
    ],
    users: [
        {id:1, login: "user1", groupId: 1},
        {id:2, login: "user2", groupId: 2},
        {id:3, login: "user3", groupId: 1}
    ]
}
```

and handlebars template:

```
{{#each users}}
    <tr data-id="{{id}}">
        <td>{{login}}</td>
        <td data-id="{{groupId}}">{{lookup ../groups groupId}}{{title}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

but it is not working. Template compile and table render, but table group column contains only id as attribute of td tag. How to render title of group inside td tag (it is possible with handlebars using this JSON object)?

Comment: What is lookup helper?

Comment: From handlebars site (http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html): The lookup helper allows for dynamic parameter resolution using Handlebars variables. This is useful for resolving values for array indexes.

Answer (score 4):

The `lookup` helper only looks up by array index, not but an id, but you can whip up a helper to do that:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('lookup2', function(collection, id) {
    var collectionLength = collection.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < collectionLength; i++) {
        if (collection[i].id === id) {
            return collection[i];
        }

    }

    return null;
});
```

Then you'll need to lookup the title from that object. Here I use `#with` to change context:

```
{{#each users}}
    <tr data-id="{{id}}">
        <td>{{login}}</td>
        <td data-id="{{groupId}}">{{#with (lookup2 ../groups groupId)}}{{title}}{{/with}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```